# How to Add Incremental Numbers to a New Column Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this simplified dataframe:

```
ID   Fruit
F1   Apple
F2   Orange
F3   Banana
```

I want to add in the begining of the dataframe a new column `df['New_ID']`  which has the number `880` that increments by one in each row.

The output should be simply like:

```
New_ID   ID   Fruit
880      F1   Apple
881      F2   Orange
882      F3   Banana
```

I tried the following:

```
df['New_ID'] = ["880"] # but I want to do this without assigning it the list of numbers literally
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Here:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={"index":"New_ID"})
df['New_ID'] = df.index + 880
```

Comment: Great solution, but it does not insert the `New_ID` column in the beginning of the dataframe.

Comment: Or do what piRSquared says, his answer is better. I should have thought of that, but I was manipulating indexes when you asked your question, and I guess I sat in the groove.

Comment: This is assuming the index is a range index.

Answer (score 201):

```
df.insert(0, 'New_ID', range(880, 880 + len(df)))
df
```

[image]

Comment: The first parameter, *loc*, is the *Insertion index* that is *0 <= loc <= len(columns)*.

Comment: Note: this modifies the dataframe in-place, i.e., don't reassign your df `df = df.insert(.....)`

Comment: @piRSquared how can I increment by float number? I need to add a "Time" column that adds 0.002 after each row starting at 0.

Answer (score 33):

You can also simply set your pandas column as list of id values with length same as of dataframe.

```
df['New_ID'] = range(880, 880+len(df))
```

Reference docs : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

Comment: This would be the best/easiest solution if it actually put the new ID column in the first position, but from what I can tell this puts it into the last position, not what OP asked for. For the issue that brought me here I don't need that, so this is the simplest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

```
df = df.assign(New_ID=[880 + i for i in xrange(len(df))])[['New_ID'] + df.columns.tolist()]

>>> df
   New_ID  ID   Fruit
0     880  F1   Apple
1     881  F2  Orange
2     882  F3  Banana
```

Answer (score 9):

I used the follow code:

```
df.insert(0, 'id', range(1, 1 + len(df)))
```

So my "id" columns is:

1, 2, 3, ...

Answer (score 2):

For a pandas DataFrame whose index starts at 0 and increments by 1 (i.e., the default values) you can just do:

```
df.insert(0, 'New_ID', df.index + 880)
```

if you want `New_ID` to be the first column. Otherwise this if you don't mind it being at the end:

```
df['New_ID'] = df.index + 880
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

df['New_ID']=np.arange(880,880+len(df.Fruit))
df=df.reindex(columns=['New_ID','ID','Fruit'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a long, chained expression, and you want to add a column with incrementing values, but you don't know the length of the dataframe (due to some of the chained expressions being groups or aggregations) you can also accomplish this by using `assign()` and a `lambda`

```py
df.assign(New_ID = lambda x: range(880, 880 + len(x))
```