# Get python to add serial nos to each entry as it is run

Tags: python-3.x, csv, header, serial-number

I am new to programming and probably there is an answer to my question somewhere like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862293/how-to-add-incremental-numbers-to-a-new-column-using-pandas), the closest i found after searching for days. Most of the info deals with existing csvs or hardcoding data. I am trying to make the program create data every time it runs and work on that so a little stumped here.

The Problem:
I can't seem to get python to attach serial nos to each entry when i run the program am making to log my study blocks. It has various fields following are two of them:

`Date        Time
12-03-2018  11:30`

Following is the code snippet:

```
d= ''
while d == '':
    d = input('Date:')
    try:
        valid_date = dt.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d')
    except ValueError:
        d = ''
        print('Please input date in YYYY-MM-DD format.')

t= ''
while t == '':
    t = input('Time:')
    try:
        valid_time = dt.strptime(t, '%H:%M')
    except ValueError:
        d = ''
        print('Please input time in HH:MM format.')

header = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames= ['UID', 'Date', 'Time', 'Topic', 'Objective', 'Why', 'Summary'], delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL )
header.writeheader()

log_input = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
log_input.writerow([d, t, topic, objective, why, summary])

outfile.close()

df = pd.read_csv('E:\Coursera\HSU\python\pom_blocks_log.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('E:\pom_blocks_log.csv')
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns[0] = 'UID'
df['UID'] = df.index

print (df)
```

I get the following error when i run the program with the df block:
   `TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations`

I new to python and don't really know how to work with data structures, so i am building small programs to learn. Any help is highly appreciated and apologies if this is a duplicate, please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

So, i figured it out. Following is the process i followed:

1. I save the CSV file using the `csv` module.
2. I load the CSV file in `pandas` as dataframe.

What this does is, it allows me to append user entries to the CSV every time the program is run and then i can load it as a dataframe and use pandas to manipulate the data accordingly. Then i added a generator to clean the lines off the delimiter character ',' so that it could be loaded as a dataframe for string columns where ',' is accepted as a valid input. Maybe this is a round about approach but, it works.

Following is the code:

```
import csv
from csv import reader
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


with open(r'E:\Coursera\HSU\08_programming\trLog_df.csv','a', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:

    # Date
    d = ''#input("Date:")
    while d == '':
        d = input('Date: ')
        try:
            valid_date = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d')
        except ValueError:
            d = ''
            print("Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")

    # Time
    t = ''#input("Date:")
    while t == '':
        t = input('Time: ')
        try:
            valid_date = datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M')
        except ValueError:
            t = ''
            print("Incorrect data format, should be HH:MM")

    log_input = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter= ',',
                    quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    log_input.writerow([d, t])

# Function to clean lines off the delimter ','
def merge_last(file_name, merge_after_col=7, skip_lines=0):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as fp:
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            if i < 2:
                continue
            spl = line.strip().split(',')
            yield (*spl[:merge_after_col], ','.join(spl[merge_after_col:2]))

# Generator to clean the lines
gen = merge_last(r'E:\Coursera\HSU\08_programming\trLog_df.csv', 1)
# get the column names
header = next(gen)
# create the data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(gen, columns=header)

df.head()

print(df)
```

If anybody has a better solution, it would be enlightening to know how to do it with efficiency and elegance.

Thank you for reading.