# Add new column with incremental increase

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
           Date      LOC_A 
0    2022-07-01        154          
1    2022-07-02        162          
2    2022-07-03        170          
3    2022-07-04        169          
4    2022-07-05        201
```

I would like to create a new column based on the data in column `LOC_A`, where the new column, let's call it `VOL_SCORE`, starts at 0 when `LOC_A` equals 160 and then increases by 1 every time the value in `LOC_A` increases by 1. Anything below 160 would be 0.

```
           Date      LOC_A   VOL_SCORE
0    2022-07-01        154       0           
1    2022-07-02        162       3        
2    2022-07-03        170      11         
3    2022-07-04        169      10         
4    2022-07-05        201      42
```

There's a similar question but I'm not sure how to apply that answer to my situation since Im attempting to create a new column.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862293/how-to-add-incremental-numbers-to-a-new-column-using-pandas#:~:text=For%20a%20pandas%20DataFrame%20whose%20index%20starts%20at,the%20end%3A%20df%20%5B%27New_ID%27%5D%20%3D%20df.index%20%2B%20880](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862293/how-to-add-incremental-numbers-to-a-new-column-using-pandas#:%7E:text=For%20a%20pandas%20DataFrame%20whose%20index%20starts%20at,the%20end%3A%20df%20%5B%27New_ID%27%5D%20%3D%20df.index%20%2B%20880)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract your reference with [`sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) and [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) the negative values to 0:

```
ref = 160
df['VOL_SCORE'] = df['LOC_A'].sub(ref-1).clip(lower=0)
```

Output:

```
         Date  LOC_A  VOL_SCORE
0  2022-07-01    154          0
1  2022-07-02    162          3
2  2022-07-03    170         11
3  2022-07-04    169         10
4  2022-07-05    201         42
```